# SQL Triggers - Deleted or Updated? or maybe something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sqltransaction

I am trying to figure out which i need to use here: deleted, inserted or updated.

basically.

I need to write some data to the history table, when the main table is updated, and only if the status changes from something to either pending or active.

This is what I have now:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_SourceHistory]  ON [dbo].[tblSource]
FOR UPDATE AS  
    DECLARE @statusOldValue char(1) 
    DECLARE @statusNewValue char(1)

    SELECT @statusOldValue = statusCode FROM deleted 
    SELECT @statusNewValue= statusCode FROM updated

    IF (@statusOldValue <> @statusNewValue) AND 
       (@statusOldValue = 'P' or @statusOldValue = 'A')
    BEGIN TRY
       INSERT * INTO tblHistoryTable)  
           select * from [DELETED]
```

so I want the new data to stay in the main table, the the history table to be updated with what is being overwritten... right now it just copies the same info over. so after update, both my tables have the same data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use both the `inserted` and `deleted` tables together to check for records that:
1. Already existed (to check it's not an insert)
2. Still exists    (to check it's not a  delete)
3. The Status field changed

You also need to make sure you do that in a set based approach, as per marc_s's answer, triggers are not single record processes.

```
INSERT INTO
  tblHistoryTable
SELECT
  deleted.*
FROM
  inserted
INNER JOIN
  deleted
    ON inserted.PrimaryKey = deleted.PrimaryKey
WHERE
  inserted.StatusCode <> deleted.StatusCode
  AND (inserted.StatusCode = 'P' OR inserted.StatusCode = 'A')
```

- inserted = the new values
- deleted  = the old values

Comment: I think it's been some time since I was last nitpicking at an answer of yours. So forgive me, please, but I couldn't go past this one. First, it's `deleted.StatusCode`, not `inserted.StatusCode`, that was supposed to be `in ('P', 'A')`. And second, your explanation about what `inserted` and `deleted` are should be either put into a comment or taken outside the code snippet. There. (But basically I agree with the script.)

Comment: The OPs code snippet does refer to the *old* status being 'P' or 'A', but textual description includes `only if the status changes from something to either pending or active`.  As the code contains other issues, I based my answer on the text.  I've editted for your other point :)

Comment: I know you won't admit it but I'm sure you've answered this question on purpose, to lure a nitpicker like me into nitpicking at your answer, only to fool them afterwards. A clever trap. ;)

Comment: I can not lie, my lure was subtle, but not subtle enough.  I shall raise my game, I shall lure you in and catch you, but without you ever knowing it happened ;)

Answer (score 7):

There are only the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables - there's no `Updated`.

For an `UPDATE`, `Inserted` contains the new values (after the update) while `Deleted` contains the old values before the update.

Also **be aware** that the triggers is fired **once per batch** - not once for each row. So both pseudo tables will potentially contain **multiple rows**! Don't just assume a single row and assign this to a variable - this

```
SELECT @statusOldValue = statusCode FROM deleted 
SELECT @statusNewValue= statusCode FROM updated
```

**will fail** if you have multiple rows ! You need to write your triggers in such a fashion that they work with **multiple rows** in `Inserted` and `Deleted` !

**Update:** yes - there **IS** a much better way to write this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_SourceHistory]  ON [dbo].[tblSource]
FOR UPDATE 
AS  
   INSERT INTO dbo.tblHistoryTable(Col1, Col2, Col3, ...., ColN)
      SELECT Col1, COl2, Col3, ..... ColN
        FROM Deleted d
        INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey
        WHERE i.statusCode <> d.statusCode
          AND d.statusCode IN ('A', 'P')
```

Basically:

- explicitly specify the columns you want to insert - both in the `INSERT` statement as well as the `SELECT` statement retrieving the data to insert - to avoid any nasty surprises
- create an `INNER JOIN` between `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo-tables to get all rows that were updated
- specify all other conditions (different status codes etc.) in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT`

This solution works for batches of rows being updated - it won't fail on a multi-row update....

Comment: yes yes a million times yes, a badly written trigger can create horrible data integrity problems.

Comment: how? what is a better way to write this?

Comment: @xrum: provided the much better way to write this - see my update in my response

Answer (score 1):

There is no `updated` table, you are looking for `inserted`.